# JqGrid not loading in web page in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am having an aspx engine view where the jqgrid must be loaded.

But the jqgrid is not loading. I tried with breakpoint using firebug but it has not hitted also

In the view

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MetaContent" runat="server">
<table  id="jqgprojectnew" style="width: 100%">
  </table>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

var url = '<%#Url.Action("Listmanoj")%>';
    var colNames = [
        'Orderid',
        'Customername',
        'Price',
        'Quantity',
        'Productname',
    'Total Including Tax',
    'Email',
    'Town',
    'Country', 'Postcode', 'Homephone','Workphone','Deliveryname','Deliverytown','Deliveryphone','Deliverypostalcode','Shippingmethod'];
    var colModel = [
        { name: 'Orderid', index: 'Orderid', align: 'left',  width: 20 },
        { name: 'Customername', index: 'Customername', edittype: 'image', align: 'left', width: 70, },
        { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', align: 'left', width: 100,  },
        { name: 'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', align: 'left', width: 150, },
        { name: 'Productname', index: 'Productname', align: 'left', width: 150 },
        { name: 'Totalincludingtax', index: 'Totalincludingtax', align: 'left', width: 150 },
        { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', align: 'left', width: 100, },
         { name: 'Town', index: 'Town', align: 'left', width: 100 },
         { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', align: 'left', width: 100,  },
          { name: 'Postcode', index: 'Postcode',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
           { name: 'Homephone', index: 'Homephone',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
         { name: 'Workphone', index: 'Workphone',  align: 'left', width: 70 },

         { name: 'Deliveryname', index: 'Deliveryname',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
         { name: 'Deliverytown', index: 'Deliverytown',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
         { name: 'Deliveryphone', index: 'Deliveryphone',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
         { name: 'Deliverypostalcode', index: 'Deliverypostalcode', align: 'left',             width: 70 },
         { name: 'Shippingmethod', index: 'Shippingmethod',  align: 'left', width: 70 }
    ];
    var sortname = 'Orderid';
    var sortorder = 'desc';
    SetGrid('#jqgprojectnew', '', url, colNames, colModel, sortname, sortorder, -1);




});
</script>
```

In the Web page view how it is loading

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {
  $("a.button").button();
   var url = '';
    var colNames = [
   'Orderid',
    'Customername',
   'Price',
    'Quantity',
      'Productname',
    'Total Including Tax',
     'Email',
      'Town',
       'Country', 'Postcode',                            'Homephone','Workphone','Deliveryname','Deliverytown','Deliveryphone','Deliverypostalcode','Shippingmethod'];
```

Code for setting grid:

```
function SetGrid(v_gridCtrl,v_pagingCtrl, v_url, v_colNames, v_colModel, v_sortname, v_sortorder, v_Pagesize) {

if (v_Pagesize == undefined)
    v_Pagesize = 100;

$(v_gridCtrl).jqGrid({
    //url from wich data should be requested
    autowidth: true,
    url: v_url,
    //type of data
    datatype: 'json',
    //url access method type
    mtype: 'POST',
    //columns names
    colNames: v_colNames,
    //columns model
    colModel: v_colModel,
    //pager for grid
    pager: $(v_pagingCtrl),
    //enable dynamic scrolling
    //scroll: true,
    //enable npage request parameter
    prmNames: { npage: 'npage' },
    //number of rows per page
    rowNum: v_Pagesize,
    rowList: [10, 30, 60, 90, 100, 150, -1],
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("option[value=-1]").text('All');
        $('#count').html($(v_gridCtrl).getGridParam("reccount"));
    },

    //initial sorting column
    sortname: v_sortname,
    //initial sorting direction
    sortorder: v_sortorder,
    //we want to display total records count
    viewrecords: true,
    //grid height
    height: 400,//'100%',
    width: '100%',
    scrollOffset: 0,
    shrinkToFit: true
});
```

}

My problems are:
The action method which is used in the jqgrid is not hitind and on load the url action result is empty

Comment: Where is this function: SetGrid()?

Comment: Set grid is where I have my jqgrid code

Comment: include that too in the question plz

Comment: Is the jqgrid visible on pageload?

Comment: No it is not visible. I have pasted the code how it is loading using firebug you can find it in the code i posted

Comment: Did you check the parameters of the SetGrid() function with firebug? Is every parameter is as u expect?

Comment: The problem the setgrid is not hitting at all to check

Comment: Include setgrid function in document.ready before calling it

Comment: It is already there in the document.ready or can you write the code here

Comment: Plz update you question with setgrid() defined within document.ready() (in the beginning itself)

Comment: You need just one document.ready() in your page

Comment: the method set grid has worked but the functionality has not been done beacuse the dynamic url is coming empty..I have code for url as below var url = '<%#Url.Action("Listmanoj")%>'; it should call Listmanoj action result in the conroller. But on the load url is becoming var url='' .any suggestion for this to load actual url rather than empty

Comment: I think that is because of this:  $("a.button").button();
   var url = '';...

Comment: I have updated my code and same problem. I am going wrong in the urlaction syntax

Comment: Try '@Url.action(..)'

Comment: this aspx engine can i try that. sorry i am new to mvc so iam asking like that

Comment: Try it. Btw, did you forget to add document. ready in the first part of your question?

Comment: Or you can change the url to, url="/ControllerName/actionName"

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but the action in the controller has not hitted by break points

Comment: So,now it hit setgrid()?

Comment: I have updated you question. Plz try with that code

Comment: CAn you please add your code as comment i could not get where you have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add document.ready() in script
- Set url like this:

  var url = '/ControllerName/Listmanoj';  //If your controller name is TestController, the url should be '/Test/Listmanoj'
- Remove the following section:(why do you need that?)

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.button").button();
         var url = '';
          var colNames = [
         'Orderid',
      'Customername',
     'Price',
      'Quantity',
        'Productname',
        'Total Including Tax',
       'Email',
        'Town',
         'Country', 'Postcode',                            'Homephone','Workphone','Deliveryname','Deliverytown','Deliveryphone','Deliverypostalcode','Shippingmethod'];
- Include setGrid in document.ready().

In short, you script section should look like:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MetaContent" runat="server">
    <table  id="jqgprojectnew" style="width: 100%">
      </table>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function()
{
//set grid function

function SetGrid(v_gridCtrl,v_pagingCtrl, v_url, v_colNames, v_colModel, v_sortname, v_sortorder, v_Pagesize) {

if (v_Pagesize == undefined)
    v_Pagesize = 100;

$(v_gridCtrl).jqGrid({
    //url from wich data should be requested
    autowidth: true,
    url: v_url,
    //type of data
    datatype: 'json',
    //url access method type
    mtype: 'POST',
    //columns names
    colNames: v_colNames,
    //columns model
    colModel: v_colModel,
    //pager for grid
    pager: $(v_pagingCtrl),
    //enable dynamic scrolling
    //scroll: true,
    //enable npage request parameter
    prmNames: { npage: 'npage' },
    //number of rows per page
    rowNum: v_Pagesize,
    rowList: [10, 30, 60, 90, 100, 150, -1],
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("option[value=-1]").text('All');
        $('#count').html($(v_gridCtrl).getGridParam("reccount"));
    },

    //initial sorting column
    sortname: v_sortname,
    //initial sorting direction
    sortorder: v_sortorder,
    //we want to display total records count
    viewrecords: true,
    //grid height
    height: 400,//'100%',
    width: '100%',
    scrollOffset: 0,
    shrinkToFit: true
});
}// end of set grid function

    var url = 'controllername/Listmanoj';
        var colNames = [
            'Orderid',
            'Customername',
            'Price',
            'Quantity',
            'Productname',
        'Total Including Tax',
        'Email',
        'Town',
        'Country', 'Postcode', 'Homephone','Workphone','Deliveryname','Deliverytown','Deliveryphone','Deliverypostalcode','Shippingmethod'];
        var colModel = [
            { name: 'Orderid', index: 'Orderid', align: 'left',  width: 20 },
            { name: 'Customername', index: 'Customername', edittype: 'image', align: 'left', width: 70, },
            { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', align: 'left', width: 100,  },
            { name: 'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', align: 'left', width: 150, },
            { name: 'Productname', index: 'Productname', align: 'left', width: 150 },
            { name: 'Totalincludingtax', index: 'Totalincludingtax', align: 'left', width: 150 },
            { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', align: 'left', width: 100, },
             { name: 'Town', index: 'Town', align: 'left', width: 100 },
             { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', align: 'left', width: 100,  },
              { name: 'Postcode', index: 'Postcode',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
               { name: 'Homephone', index: 'Homephone',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
             { name: 'Workphone', index: 'Workphone',  align: 'left', width: 70 },

             { name: 'Deliveryname', index: 'Deliveryname',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
             { name: 'Deliverytown', index: 'Deliverytown',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
             { name: 'Deliveryphone', index: 'Deliveryphone',  align: 'left', width: 70 },
             { name: 'Deliverypostalcode', index: 'Deliverypostalcode', align: 'left',             width: 70 },
             { name: 'Shippingmethod', index: 'Shippingmethod',  align: 'left', width: 70 }
        ];
        var sortname = 'Orderid';
        var sortorder = 'desc';
        SetGrid('#jqgprojectnew', '', url, colNames, colModel, sortname, sortorder, -1);




    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Listmanoj action  in the controller is not hitting that was the only problem left

Comment: What is the value of url now?

Comment: And plz post action method

Comment: What about the value of url? Did you check with firebug?

Comment: the value of the is returing the same as above its is fine

Comment: What s the controller name?

Comment: CheckoutController is the controller name

Comment: If it is not working, remove the url property from the jqgrid and check whether an empty grid is shown on pageload. If it is not visible, the problem is with your jqgrid code.

Comment: Your URL should be  '/Checkout/Listmanoj' (suffix-'Controller' not needed)